# How can I display a javascript webpage inside a WebView in JavaFx 2.0 in Browser

Tags: javafx-2

I am trying to display a `twitterBox` inside a webview in a JavaFx 2.0 web application. Is there any know problems with trying to do this? When I launch the application from my desktop the script shows up but from the browser it doesn't load the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sign your application.

Being run in browser JavaFX applications falls under restrictions of Java plugin and you twitterBox can't connect to another domain twitter.com.

If you are using NetBeans you can self-sign application in Project Properties.
Otherwise look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/deployment/javafx_ant_task_reference001.htm#CIAJGAFH

Comment: I just ran into the same issue, I signed the application and I cant see the webview webpage

Comment: Artur, it's no enough information. What does Java Console say?

Comment: I tried running the Java Console but it only says that a runtime error has occurred

Comment: I think that Netbeans doesn't update the config files for a Java FX project correctly, at leas t it wont clean up a project correctly when options are changed in the project properties. For example I had to start a new project and import the java files into it for my app to work. I had added a preloader application and then I removed it and deleted the preloader project. That was two days ago, since I have been updating the app and now I tried to test it and ran into all kinds of problems.