# Cannot display web page on WebView control

Tags: javascript, javafx-2

I tried to follow the instruction describe here: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm   to display a web page on javafx 2.1, but web page does not display although I've already signed my application using javafx-ant tool (this link mentions about signing javafx application [How can I display a javascript webpage inside a WebView in JavaFx 2.0 in Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497850/how-can-i-display-a-javascript-webpage-inside-a-webview-in-javafx-2-0-in-browser)).

I can view the web page when running javafx on browser, but can't view it when running application as java stand alone application.

Here's the code:

browser control:

```
public class Browser extends Region {

    final WebView browser = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();

    public Browser() {
        //apply the styles
        getStyleClass().add("browser");
        // load the web page
        webEngine.load("http://www.google.com");
        //add the web view to the scene
        getChildren().add(browser);


    }
    //...
}
```

Display it:

```
  Stage stage = new Stage();

    stage.setTitle("Web View");
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Browser(),590,400, Color.web("#666970"));
    stage.setScene(scene);
    scene.getStylesheets().add("/com/sai/javafx/calendar/styles/BrowserToolbar.css");  

  stage.show();
```

Any idea would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I tagged javascript here 'cause I tried to integrate jQuery into JavaFX 2.0 app using WebView control.

Comment: Have you tried to load a simple html file without css, javascript and probably from the local file system? Does your standalone app ie jar file contain all resources in a right place? Have you tried to build and run your app in Netbeans? IDE may give you some clues.

Comment: I can load web page from a local html file, I use eclipse Helios to run my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way to solve my problem is loading the .html file locally (can't load web page from other domain, and this html file must not refer to any external link)

```
public Browser() {
   //apply the styles
   getStyleClass().add("browser");        
   // load the web page
   final URL urlHello = Browser.class.getResource("sample.html");
   webEngine.load(urlHello.toExternalForm());
}
```

Display it:

```
Stage stage = new Stage();

stage.setTitle("Web View");
Scene scene = new Scene(new Browser(),590,400, Color.web("#666970"));
stage.setScene(scene);
scene.getStylesheets().add("/com/sai/javafx/calendar/styles/BrowserToolbar.css");  

stage.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample app:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class WebViewSample extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
  @Override public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {
    final WebView webView = new WebView(); 
    webView.getEngine().load("http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(webView));
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

Here is what it looks like in a browser, the inner scrollpane is the JavaFX WebView rendered browser and the outer text is the html page embedding the JavaFX WebView.

[image: WebView in Browser Sample Image]

To run it I used [NetBeans nightly build](http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/), [JavaFX 2.2b4](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html), [JDK7u6ea](http://jdk7.java.net/archive/7u6-b07.html), Win7, IE9.

Steps in NetBeans were:

1. New Project | JavaFX | JavaFX Application
2. Create a Java file with the sample app code.
3. After project created, right click Project | Properties

   - Build | Deployment | Check "Request Unrestricted Access"
   - Run | Check radio Run "in Browser"
   - OK to accept property changes
4. Press F6 to run the application in the browser.
5. Accept any security dialog warnings.
6. Wait a few seconds for the WebView to load.

Comment: Tks for your help, maybe my question does not contain enough information (I've just updated).I can view the web page when running on web browser, but can not view the web page when running application as java stand alone apps.
Besides, I use maven to build and deploy my source code, not using NetBean IDE.

Comment: If you run the sample app I supplied as a stand alone app, does it display a web page on your system? (It does on mine). If not, you will need to provide more environment details and your maven scripts and/or more code to get further assistance.  You don't need to sign a stand alone app - only apps to be deployed in browsers or webstart.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't run the javafx application although using Netbean IDE.
I use javafx-ant build tool so the result should be the same with NetBean IDE (as far as I know, NetBean IDE uses javafx-ant build tool too)

Comment: You don't need NetBeans or the javafx-ant build tool to run a JavaFX application.  Just run the following commands (adjusted for the path to your JavaFX sdk): `javac -cp "\Program Files\Oracle\JavaFX 2.1 SDK\rt\lib\jfxrt.jar" WebViewSample.java`  `java -cp "\Program Files\Oracle\JavaFX 2.1 SDK\rt\lib\jfxrt.jar;." WebViewSample` - Hopefully that works, otherwise I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right for compiling and running javafx application as standalone one, but in my case, I use javafx-ant build tool to compile and sign my application as a web start app.
It seems that when running as a java standalone application, there're some restrictions that prevent the web page displayed. I still can not run the javafx application as standalone. Still investigating.